# How do I convert String.split to int

Tags: java, string, date, java-time, localdate

```
    String nDate;
    String dateTemp;
    int i;

    nDate = kb.nextLine();
    String[] temp = nDate.split("-");
    int numDate = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(temp));
```

im having issues with the (temp) part in the last line. If for example my input is "06-21-2020", what I want to happen is it becomes "06212020"

Comment: What you're trying to do is not splitting, it's replacing `'-'` with nothing. Use [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) instead.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use strings nor integers for your dates (just as you don’t use strings and integers for floating-point values and Booleans — I hope). Use `LocalDate` for a date (like you use `int` or `long` for an integer). See the answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash.

Comment: Also while you can get 6212020 as an integer value, you can’t from that value tell that there originally was a leading zero.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) instead of `split()`. To further explain, `String.valueOf()` does not take an array of `String`s.

```
String temp = nDate.replace("-","");
int numDate Integer.parseInt(temp);
```

Answer (score 3):

## *java.time*

The [answer by Phaelax z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68165107/10819573) is spot-on for your specific requirement.

However, I recommend you parse the date string to `LocalDate` and format it as you wish.

You will get much more than the required conversion e.g. just think of finding the name of the day on 06-21-2020 or something like converting to some other format e.g. Sun 21 June 2020. All such requirements can be easily done using the in-built API as shown in the following demo:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nDate = "06-21-2020";

        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(nDate, dtfInput);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMdduuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE dd MMM uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dtfOutput1.format(date));
        System.out.println(dtfOutput2.format(date));
        System.out.println(dtfOutput3.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
06212020
21/06/2020
Sun 21 Jun 2020
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/jRNIm9)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.